# Large file uploader

Tags: php

I made a basic upload script by using the w3schools tutorial ([here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)) and I was basically wondering if there was anyway to increase the upload size to above 5Gb. I tried changing the script to upload large video files but it errors telling me that the file is too big.
Would anyone be able to help me with the issue that I am having

To try the uploader for yourselves ([uploader](http://samstreettesting.webuda.com/)), it accepts .mov formats, but like I say my error lies within the upload file size.

Comment: What file system do you have on the php's guest os ?

Comment: I think this has to do with your server.http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

Comment: I would probably avoid W3Schools tutorials.  It's been a long time since I've looked through them at depth, but as of a while back, they ranged from mediocre to terrible.  Unfortunately, I don't know a good PHP tutorial off the top of my head (maybe someone else will?).  On a different note: a 5GB upload is *huge*.  Unless there's an extremely fast connection, that's going to probably involve either the client or server timing out a decent amount of the time (though clients should know to not time out unless the connection drops, and only a thread or process based server would have problems).

Comment: i just came up with an idea of uploading them in chunck to avoid timeouts. You could read part of file and upload with ajax, and when it completes, take next part and repeat until done.. just a thought ^^

Comment: You can use the new JavaScript [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) together with the slice() methode, to split the upload into chunks, though it will only work with newer browsers. (http://dnduploader.filkor.org/FAQ/)

Another way would be to use a Java Applet.

Comment: @Tom - this might sound silly, but if I upload in chunks will the file be a full file on the server or will I have to build it back together once its on the server?

Comment: ofcourse you need some script to handle chunks again on serverside ^^ I want to let you know that it was just a quick thought, not tested concept.

Comment: Nice one :), this is definitely something I will look into. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned in the comments you can 'chunk' the file into slices, and upload them piece-by-piece. The server will merge the files after all slices were uploaded.
A working demo for this is http://dnduploader.filkor.org.
You can learn from it's source code, what you can find on Github (see the FAQ section on the page).

In general, it's not an easy task to create such an uploader, but from it you can learn some novel ideas about the current 'trends' of file uploading..

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Critical Point, you will most likely need to chunk the upload.

There are a number of other additional factors to be aware of - for example error recovery and connection interruption.

It may not be suitable for your uses, but in the past I have had success using a commercial component:

http://www.aurigma.com/UploadSuite/

There is a fairly steep entry price, but provided are multi-platform components for both client and server side. In terms of comparison to building and troubleshooting a home-made solution, Aurigma provides great ROI.